# Pandas Set a Column at specific Rows to True based on Column Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe:

```
0 A B C D
1 3 5 1 True
2 4 2 1 True
3 3 5 0 False
```

What I am trying to do is If the values of Cols A, B paired together anywhere in Col D have a True set all rows of Col D to True where Col A, B pairing is maintained.

Ex:
Col A, B: 3, 5. Set Col D to True everywhere Col A, B = 3, 5 if Col D equals True Anywhere for Col A, B = 3, 5

I believe this is easy enough to do with iterating through the dataframe, but I couldn't think of a way to use the built in functions of pandas or numpy. If you know of a way I would be much appreciated on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df["new_D"] = df.groupby(["A", "B"]).D.transform(any)
```

Grouping over `A, B` and then `transform`ing the `D` column such that it gets `True` if `any`where in the group there is a `True`; else it gets `False`.

to get

```
       0    A    B    C      D  new_D
0    1.0  3.0  5.0  1.0   True   True
1    2.0  4.0  2.0  1.0   True   True
2    3.0  3.0  5.0  0.0  False   True
```

Comment: Awesome. I knew there would be a better way than a loop. My only question now is: Is there a way to do it in place instead of creating a new column? Or shall I just drop D afterwards

Comment: @GrahamChapman  you can write `df.D = df.groupby(["A", "B"]).D.transform(any)` and it will assign it back to `D` column.

Comment: I am not able to use df.D I am using python 3.7 pandas 1.2.4, is there a conversion necessary? Like df['D']? When I try df['D'] I get an unhashable type: 'list' error

Comment: @GrahamChapman Interesting, what error does it give when you try `df.D = ...`?

Comment: Actually, I get the same error. unhashable type: list

Comment: @GrahamChapman Are you trying the sample data you posted here or on another data? Because it seems to work with the data you shared given the versions.

Comment: I am not using the sample data. I am trying to apply it to my own data, however I validated that the dtypes of the columns are for A, B (equivalent columns) are float64 and for D it is bool

Comment: Sorry, @Mustafa Aydin, I cannot move to chat. Blocked by Work ISP

Comment: @GrahamChapman np, do you get error when you do only `df.groupby(["A", "B"])`?

Comment: @GrahamChapman and what do these say: `len(df) == len(df.explode("A"))` and `B` instead of `A`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The problem was actually due to a typo. I was accidently doing df.groupby(["A"], ["B"]) as opposed to df.groupby(["A", "B"]). I wasn't able to spot it until your comment about doing only the groupby by itself